# Length of a sequential table in Lua may skip indices?

Tags: lua, indices, lua-table

In Lua is seems that if a single numeric key is missing from the table, the length still continues counting:

```
> print(#{[1]=1,[2]=2,[4]=4})
4
```

But this skipping two indices stops at the break

```
> print(#{[1]=1,[2]=2,[5]=5})
2
```

It's not just the unconvential constructor.  Even if an skipped index is created after the creation of the table it still counts past it, so long the break is only one.

```
> x={1,2}
> print(#x)
2
> x[4]=4
> print(#x)
```

Is this an implementation error or is this how Lua supposed to work.  Why is it like this? Any references to documentation of this would be interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it works. The length of a table is only defined if the table is a sequence,  with no holes.   See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6   .

Comment: Thanks. I understand '#' is really only meant for sequential tables, and that this may be lua's excuse for this behavior, it just seems odd how it handles this '#' in non sequential tables.